# Cassandra sample trigger to get the deleted row and column values

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

ITrigger augment method is invoked when there is update in a column family. How do we know if the update operation is insert or delete?

Also, is it possible to execute any DML statements in other tables in the same keyspace in the trigger implementation? Assume that there are two tables test1 and test2. Trigger is created for test1. If there is any delete operation in test1, how do we execute DML statements for test2 in the trigger implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to check the update operation is delete or insert

```
@Override
public Collection<Mutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update) {
    if (!update.deletionInfo().isLive()) {
        System.out.println("Delete Operation");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Insert Operation");
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error ColumnFamily cannot be resolved to type. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bhargavaravalikoganti The trigger code is for Cassandra 2.x. What is your cassandra version ?

Comment: I am using 3.10.

Comment: Thanks for link. But, I keep getting errors like there is not method deletion() or cell(). And is this an override method? How do I get only partition from cassandra, I'm able to get the resultset. How to extract partition?

Comment: Add all the jar from Cassandra lib as library

Comment: How do I initialize a partition variable?

Comment: Check this code https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java

Comment: Thanks, but I do not get a clear picture on utilizing it. This(https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/examples/triggers/src/org/apache/cassandra/triggers/AuditTrigger.java) audit trigger is the custom trigger jar file which I used. So, where do I have to override it? How do I call the overridden method. Could you please make it more understandable and clear.