# Sample code for Cassandra trigger

Tags: triggers, cassandra-2.0, cql3

First of all the basic question is -> how to implement trigger in Cassandra?

How do I make delete operation in multiple tables in Cassandra Trigger. Is there any sample code for delete? If there is any detailed documentation on Cassandra Trigger with sample codes it would be very helpful.

Thanks
Chaity

Answer (score 1):

you can find here a Documentation about using CQL

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/trigger_r.html

It's this maybe you want to have?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At first I want to know if there is anything wrong in this question so that I can correct myself. After doing a lot of searching I did not find anything detailed on delete in multiple tables so I posted this question here. I have already tried this InvertedIndex example.The link you mentioned does have any example for delete?
(NOTE: This example is limited to append-only workloads, doesn't delete indexes on deletes.) To use trigger in C* we have to implement our own trigger logic. I have tested insert and update in multiple tables but cannot find any example for delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722332/cassandra-sample-trigger-to-get-the-deleted-row-and-column-values

There was another question related C* trigger. But unfortunately no answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late fore response

In order to implement Cassandra Trigger, you need to:

1. implement `ITrigger` interface from [Cassandra Maven Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-all)
2. build jar with dependencies and place it under `/etc/cassandra/triggers` folder (location may vary depending on environment: docker, local and etc)
3. start Cassandra and execute `CREATE TRIGGER ...` cql query

You can check my sample project https://github.com/timurt/cassandra-trigger

Inside I implemented detection of the `insert`,`update`,`delete` operations for `partition`,`row`,`cell` entities

Hope this will help you!