# cassandra trigger create vs update

Tags: triggers, cassandra

I need to implement a cassandra trigger in java that will take a different action for INSERT vs UPDATE operations.

I've seen how it is possible to identify a DELETE operation in the question [Cassandra sample trigger to get the deleted row and column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31722332/cassandra-sample-trigger-to-get-the-deleted-row-and-column-values) but I can't see any methods in the ColumnFamily object that would allow allow the code to differentiate between INSERT vs UPDATE, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't conceptually any difference between **INSERT** and **UPDATE**. Indeed an INSERT and an UPDATE are just mutation. Cassandra gives them different name so that people coming from the relational DB have familiar concepts

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I knew there was no difference from the database perspective but I was hoping there would be a way to differentiate in the trigger because the particular application cares about whether a new row was created or an existing one was updated.

Comment: There is a trick at the storage engine to distinguish between INSERT vs UPDATE. INSERT operations always create a **row marker**. I don't know if you can access this information or not from the Trigger API

Answer (score 0):

As [@doanduyhai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/873530/doanduyhai) mentioned and according to [Casssandra sources](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/statements/UpdateStatement.java#L72) only **INSERT** operation updates row timestamp (LivenessInfo).
For other operations this timestamp is not updated and equals Long.MIN_VALUE.

Custom Trigger which checks for **INSERT** operation

```
public class CustomTrigger implements ITrigger {
    @Override
    public Collection<Mutation> augment(Partition partition) {
        checkQueryType(partition));
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    private void checkQueryType(Partition partition) { 
        UnfilteredRowIterator it = partition.unfilteredIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Unfiltered unfiltered = it.next();
            Row row = (Row) unfiltered;
            if (isInsert(row)) {
                // Implement insert related logic
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isInsert(Row row) {
        return row.primaryKeyLivenessInfo().timestamp() != Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```